# Pandas Column filled with dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have the following problem. I currently have a DataFrame that is filled with various position data. One column is unfortunately filled with a large list containing various dictionaries. I would like to display the contents of the dictionaries as columns in the dataframe so that I can edit them. The current Df looks like that:

| Time | Returncode | position.vars |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02.02.2017 13:01 | OK | [{"key": "Positionsdaten", "value": "1", "vartype": 1}, {"key": "PositionX", "value: 11", "vartype" 1}, {"key": "PositionY", "value: 9", "vartype" 1}, {"key": "PositionZ", "value: 1", "vartype" 1}] |
| 02.02.2017 13:05 | OK | {"key": "Positionsdaten", "value": "1", "vartype": 1}, {"key": "PositionX", "value: 3", "vartype" 1}, {"key": "PositionY", "value: 1", "vartype" 1}, {"key": "PositionZ", "value: 0", "vartype" 1}] |

My goal is that the Df looks like that

| Time | Returncode | PositionY | PositionX | PositionZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02.02.2017 13:01 | OK | 11 | 9 | 1 |

I already tried normalize, but that results in an Attribute Error

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(df["position.vars"].dropna()

AttributeError: 'list' has no attribute 'values'
```

I was also thinking to create a dict from the dataframe and then manually remove unnecessary data. However I keep getting Type Errors

```
df1 = df["position.vars"] 
didct = df1.to_dict
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Your "position.vars" column contains `dict` with invalid syntax, You should make a reproducible question so that people can help you find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extract df.loc[0,'position.vars']. Now that your dictionary is out, you can access easily its data which you can then bring back in the format that you like in the original df dataframe.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

`pd.json_normalize()` takes a dict or list of dicts as input data ([Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)) so you can't pass a Pandas Series to it, hence the error.
The correct input for `pandas.json_normalize()` should be each value in the column, for example: `pd.json_normalize(df.loc[0,'position.vars'])` should return the following DataFrame *(assuming that the value is a valid `dict`, your sample code is not)*
|   |key    |value  |vartype|
|---|----|---|---|
|0  |Positionsdaten |1  |1|
|1  |PositionX  |11 |1|
|2  |PositionY  |9  |1|
|3  |PositionZ  |1  |1|

To normalize the entire column (which is a Pandas Series), you can use the `.apply()` method: `df['position.vars'].apply(pd.json_normalize)`, but it will not produce the result you expected, which is  to have the value of the key `key` as column name and value of the key `value` as row value. For that you will need a little bit more wrangling:

```
df['position.vars'].apply(lambda x: pd.json_normalize(x).set_index('key')['value'])
```

Finally, a one-liner to normalize the dictionaries and join with the original DataFrame:

```
df.join(df['position.vars'].apply(lambda x: pd.json_normalize(x).set_index('key')['value']))
```